# Solving ODE by contraction mapping

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let a and c be real numbers. Solve the initial value problem y'(x) = ay(x), y(0) = c on the interval [0, 1/2a] with the help of the contraction mapping theorem.

I understand that solving this ODE is equivalent to finding the fixed point of a contraction map, but im not sure about the grunt work. (i found this idea online and it simply mentions it in passing.)

Let f1(t) = c and deﬁne fn+1 = Φ(fn). How would you compute f2?

Comment: What is $\phi$?

Comment: \phi is the contraction map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi: C[0,\frac{1}{2a}] \to C[0,\frac{1}{2a}]$ be defined by $\phi(y)(t) = c + \int_0^t a y(\tau) d \tau$.

Note that $|\phi(y_1)(t)-\phi(y_2)(t) | \le \int_0^t a d \tau \|y_1-y_2\|_\infty \le \frac{1}{2} \|y_1-y_2\|_\infty $, and so $\|\phi(y_1)-\phi(y_2)\|_\infty \le \frac{1}{2} \|y_1-y_2\|_\infty $. Hence $\phi$ is a contraction map.

The iteration is given by $y_{n+1} = \phi(y_n)$, starting with $y_1(t) = c$.

Hence $y_2(t) = \phi(y_1)(t) = c + \int_0^t a y_1(\tau) d \tau = c+ atc = (1+at)c$.

$y_3(t) = c+ \int_0^t a y_2(\tau) d \tau = c + \int_0^t a (1+at)c d \tau = c+ atc + \frac{1}{2} a^2 t^2 c = (1+at + \frac{1}{2} (at)^2) c$.

Notice the emerging pattern, use induction to confirm that it is true.